# Auth0 Login Button - Invalid Hook Call Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tryingto familiarize myself with Auth0 and ran into an issue. I have been following their tutorial https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react to built a single page app. Unfortunately I do not know a lot about javascript :( So I have configured a Login Button like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  return <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Log In</button>;
};

export default LoginButton;
```

The Tutorial then states to simply add the button but i don't know how, this is what I have done but it throws the invalid hook error:

```
import { React } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './styles.css';
import '../components/Auth0LoginButton';
import LoginButton from "../components/Auth0LoginButton";

export default function HomePage(){

    return (
        
        <div className="MainContent">
            <p class="Content">Please LogIn to continue</p>
            
             <>
                <button 
                    variant="primary"
                    id="LoginBtn"
                    onClick={() => LoginButton()}
                    
                    >
                        Login
                </button>
             </>   
            <p>
                <Link to="./UserPage"> Access UserPage</Link>
            </p>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Does anyone now how to do it properly? I am assuming I am calling the button wrong...

Comment: loginbutton is a component you already have the onlick bound to it, just render it in the homepage

Comment: You are calling function which renders button on button click. Instead, u can just render the button.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here but how do I do that? I though i can just call it inside a html tag....

Comment: <div className="MainContent">
            <p class="Content">Please LogIn to continue</p>
            
             
                <LoginButton/>
            
            <p>
                <Link to="./UserPage"> Access UserPage</Link>
            </p>
        </div>

Comment: The component that you are creating should be used as an html tag in other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new button:

```
<button variant="primary" id="LoginBtn" onClick={() => LoginButton()}>
      Login
  </button>
```

call the LoginButton component

```
<LoginButton/>
```

You have the onclick action defined inside that component already

Comment: Awesome thanks a million! Probably a beginner's question but thanks for answering anyways, that seems to have done the trick!